# Why is Earth considered an inertial frame of reference in common examples of interstellar relativistic motion?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, earth

Such as in the twins paradox. If relativity requires inertial frames to be applicable then how does a rotating, revolving planet count?

Answer (score 3):

Because the acceleration at any point on the Earth's surface is so small it can be neglected in illustrative examples of SR.

Answer (score 1):

The centipetal accelerations of the Earth's roation around its axis and revolution around the Sun are very small. For that matter, $1$ g is very small for many relativistic and/or astrophysical applications.

For example, after $1$ year of acceleration at $1$ g, your speed would be $0.77$ c. See [The Relativistic Rocket](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html)

The surface gravity of a typical neutron star is $2 \cdot 10^{11}$ g. See the Wikipedia  [Neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) article.

By contrast, the acceleration of Earth's rotation is small even by everyday standards.

$$a = \omega^2r = (2 \pi/T)^2r$$

Given Earth's rotational period is $86400$ sec and equatorial radius is $6.378 \cdot 10^6$ m.

$$a = 3.37 \cdot 10^{-2} \space m/s^2 = 0.0034 \space g$$

The orbital acceleration is also small. T = $1$ year = $3.156 \cdot 10^7$ sec, and the average orbital radius is $1.49 \cdot 10^{11}$ m

$$a = 0.0591 \space m/s^2 = 0.00602 \space g$$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, in special relativity, we treat the home planet as inertial (in particular, not rotating or revolving).

We do a similar thing with PHY 101 projectile motion.